# Start swing gui in anouther thread different from main to update jtextarea while doing culculations

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

My program starts at the moment

```
          public static void main(String[] args){
          new Gui().setVisible(true);
         new Program();   }
```

I am using Jtextarea to display results.
I have method in Gui display(String). it appends text to Jtextarea.
I call display(String ) from Program to display result. I have methods in Program to do some work and call that method to display at the end of execution the Program method. But if I call display(String) at the beginning of execution it will not display in Jtextarea untill method of the Program finishes. It not updating the Gui. I think I need to use invoklater and new runnable to start EDT for Gui but how to do it in main together with new Program.
So what whould be the solution for this problem? 
Thank you for your help.

P.S. I did Googled but can't get it how to do it. So this is the last resource

Comment: Post the rest of your code (preferrably a [short version](http://sscce.org/))

Comment: Please have a look at [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), or as per your approach, you can have a look at this example [using Threads](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mze59q6ylbrmlz4/Sync.java)

Answer (score 1):

A big thing that everyone seems to be overlooking: This is an actual quote from the swing documentation for `JTextArea.append`:

> This method is thread safe, although most Swing methods are not. Please see How to Use
>   Threads for more information.

So it seems that `SwingUtilities.invokelater` should have nothing to do with this. I really don't know what's causing your problem. If you post some code, I might be able to help more.

P. S: I would have put this as a comment, but I do not have the reputation to do so.

Comment: It is not the call to this `append()` method, its actually the work which is being done inside the `Program` class, which is of concern, which might be blocking the `Event Dispatcher Thread`, that is why the push to use `SwingWorker` to run that task in background. Though +1 for the provided information :-)